# Trying to use git subtree but getting an errors

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-subtree, gitkraken, github-desktop

I want to use a few repositories as a sub-directory in my project. I chose to use git subtree, but unfortunately, I can't get it work. I use Github Desktop, SourceTree, and GitKraken - but only for SourceTree, I see an option to use git subtree properly.

I added a new repository to as a git subtree, but when I try to pull this remote repository with squash commits option or without it, it gives me an errors no matter what:

1) When squash commits enabled it says - "Can't squash-merge: 'my-project\Project.Application\Examples\Projects' was never added.".

2) When squash commits disabled it says: "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories".

My current branch is a new branch (not a master branch).

I have no ideas what's wrong here, someone can see a problem here? Maybe have I to use another git client?

Thank you very much for reading this.